# SVG text animated on path working only in Firefox

Tags: css, animation, svg, svg-animate

I'm trying to solve an issue with an SVG text which should be animated on a path.

What I'm trying to accomplish is shown on https://readymade-tv.vercel.app/ (has to be opened in Firefox)

Code for this SVG is available here: https://gist.github.com/vojtechjurasek/1a63f05aaa4f300c31ac2dc677916678

**The problem**

I'm not able to make it work in any other browser than Firefox. In Safari (macOS) the text is on top of itself. In Chrome there is no text at all.

And in Firefox there is small issue with "dropping" a last letter during the animation - you can see that in top left corner of the path.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hey Vojtěch: please include the example code here so we can help you faster and your question does not depend on external links that may rot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason using a rectangle doesn't seem to work in other browsers.
You can get it running by replacing the **rect** with an identical looking **path** though.

You also need to set the **textLength** of the **textPath** to **automatic**, else the letters overlap in Chrome etc.

Based on your code, this worked for me. Though the performance in Chrome seems to be bad:

```html
<svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="1920"
      height="1080"
      viewBox="0 0 1920 1080"
    >
    <path d="M180,40 1740,40S1860,40 1860,160L1860,920S1860,1040 1740,1040L180,1040S60,1040 60,920L60,160S60,40 180,40Z" 
        id="runpath" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>

      <text textAnchor="right" fill="black" style="font-size: 20px">
        <textPath
          href="#runpath"
          side="left"
          textAnchor="right"
          spacing="auto"
          startOffset="100%"
          textLength="auto"
        >
          <animate
            attributeName="startOffset"
            from="-2.3%"
            to="0%"
            begin="0s"
            dur="2.35s"
            repeatCount="indefinite"
          ></animate>
          ADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADEREADYMADE
        </textPath>
      </text>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Hey, great job! I got closer to result I need. Still not perfect, but way closer than when I started. I'm updating the progress on the same [link](https://readymade-tv.vercel.app/).

Thank you!